# google calendar api token expires in 7 days

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I used [this guide](https://github.com/aristosv/google_auth) to create a Google calendar **OAuth2** client id and client secret. I then used this gcalcli command to create an API access token:

```
gcalcli --noauth_local_webserver --client-id=$clientid --client-secret=$clientsecret --config-folder $path/auth agenda
```

This worked fine, and the command showed me a list of google calendar events.

It also created this token `$path/auth/oauth` which allows me to run the command again without having to authenticate every time, since the saved token does that for me.

My problem is that for some reason the `oauth` token expires every 7 days, and then I have to go through the same process again, to create a new token.

There's an entry in the `oauth` file showing `"expires_in": 83,` whereas other times I went through the same process the entry was `"expires_in": 3599,`. I'm assuming this entry defines the longevity of the token but I'm not 100% sure.

So my question is, why this token expires in a week, and what can I do to extend it for a longer period of time?

**Additional information:**
This is basically a bash script running on Debian 11. It runs gcalcli, gets a list of google calendar events and sends reminders via sms.

I realise theres a way to use the refresh token to renew the access token, but it's not something I got around doing yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be clear `Access tokens` expire within an hour, `Refresh tokens` are used to request a new access token when the refresh token has expired.

If you are seeing your app stopping working after seven days its due to the following.  You are probably getting an `invalid token` error.

If you check the documentation for [expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) it states

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

The solution is to set your app to production

[image]

> I realize there's a way to use the refresh token to renew the access token, but it's not something I got around doing yet.

If you are seeing your code stop working after seven days something in your code is using the refresh token already.   I did a bit of digging in [gcalcli](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli/blob/caf5f6633c1e483456da3fdbdbbf39eb2bbf6bc0/docs/README.md) internally it uses the `Google api python client library`.  This is what is refreshing your access token.   [#L132](https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli/blob/d7c8117333fd2052209decfe8a70d343d7bb293d/gcalcli/gcal.py#L132)

Comment: agreed, but that's the `refresh` token, not the `access` token. And when the `refresh` token expires (in a week), the `access` token should not be affected.

Comment: Access tokens by default expire after an hour. Technically they are self contained. If you do manage to get your refresh token expired at the exact same time that you have requested a new access token. Then technically your access token will continue to work for the remainder of the hour that its valid.

Comment: `gcalcli internally it uses the Google api php client library. This is what is refreshing your access token. #L132` I had no idea gcalcli took care of that. I was under the impression that the access token simply had a 10 year lifespan because of the `"expires_in": 3599,` entry in the .json file. Thank you.

Comment: Pro tip :  expires_in is in seconds 

Comment: Actually its the python client library not the php client llibrary.